# Pysparse installation ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scientific-computing, sparse-matrix

I am having trouble installing pysparse on ubuntu. I installed the package python-sparse, but when running the example code found in the documentation

```
from pysparse.sparse import spmatrix
from pysparse.direct import superlu
import numpy
n = 100
A = poisson2d_sym_blk(n)
b = numpy.ones(n*n)
x = numpy.empty(n*n)
LU = superlu.factorize(A.to_csr(), diag_pivot_thresh=0.0)
LU.solve(b, x)
```

I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparse2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysparse.sparse import spmatrix
ImportError: No module named sparse
```

I have also tried running

```
$ pip install pysparse
Requirement already satisfied: pysparse in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Installing collected packages: pysparse
Successfully installed pysparse
```

Why does the example code from the documentation not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? As I can see, pip is linked to python2.6; but as far as I know the default python installation in Ubuntu since a few versions ago is 2.7.... can you that you are invoking the correct interpreter?

Comment: have you tried `from pysparse import sparse` and then just using `sparse.spmatrix`?

Answer (score 1):

I replicated the error you are having on Ubuntu v11.10 and your code looks just like the example code from the pysparse website ( http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/fact.html ).

Possible reasons:

- The example is old and the pysparse module layout has changed since the example was written (most likely)
- It is possible that the author/maintainer of the pysparse Ubuntu package change the module layout so that the import path is different.

When I run dir() on the module to view the namespace of the module, I don't see "sparse" or "direct" names but I do see the classes directly.

`$> python`

Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:12:53)

>>> import pysparse

>>> dir(pysparse)

['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'itsolvers', 'jdsym', 'os', 'precon', 'sparray', 'spmatrix', 'superlu', 'umfpack']

Change your import statements to:

`from pysparse import spmatrix`

from pysparse import superlu

and the test code should work.